# Vim urlsnippets tabstop in snip.rv is output as a str, how to use tab stop in it?

Tags: vim

I guess the core code is

```
snip.rv='\`\`\`mermaid\n graph $1'+out+'\`\`\`'
```

I want to use tabstop $1 in the snip.rv and if possible, in the var out.

The complete code shows below:

```
snippet '(?<!\\)([0-9])([0-9])gtb' "graphy" r
$1`!p 
x=match.group(1)
y=match.group(2)
row1=""
for i in range(int(x)):
    row1+=" -->"
row1+="\n"
out=int(y)*row1
snip.rv='\`\`\`mermaid\n graph $1'+out+'\`\`\`'
`$0
endsnippet
```

Comment: I see that what you meant by tabstop and what I understood are very different. Apologies

Comment: Sorry，maybe it's my poor english that cause it. I've tried my best to express.

Answer (score 2):

You're using Python interpolation (`` `!p ...` ``) in your snippet and UltiSnips will not perform any placeholder substitutions inside the embedded Python code itself. (Doing so would be problematic for many reasons related to escaping the Python terms and strings.)

Instead, UltiSnips will export the placeholders in a `t` variable that you can access inside the Python code.

See [the docs](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/3.2/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L893) on variables available from within a Python interpolation block, which includes:

```
t   - The values of the placeholders, t[1] is the text of ${1}, etc.
```

So you can actually just use `t[1]` as a Python variable in that line of the code, something like the below:

```
snip.rv='\`\`\`mermaid\n graph '+t[1]+out+'\`\`\`'
```

Comment: Hello, I encounter another problem with your suggertion. The t[1] actually won't show in the output, however, when I press tab, it seem doesn't work as tabstop either. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help and I finally know I can use

```
snip.expand_anon(anon_snippet_table)
```

way to get what I want

```
def create_gtable(snip):    
    # retrieving single line from current string and treat it like tabstops count
    placeholders_string = snip.buffer[snip.line].strip()
    rows_amount = int(placeholders_string[0])
    columns_amount = int(placeholders_string[1])

    # erase current line
    snip.buffer[snip.line] = ''

    # create anonymous snippet with expected content and number of tabstops
    anon_snippet_title = "\`\`\`mermaid\n graph "+'$1' + "\n"
    anon_snippet_end="\`\`\`"
    anon_snippet_body = ""
    for row in range(1,rows_amount+1):
        anon_snippet_body += ' -> '.join(['$' + str(row*columns_amount+col+1) for col in range(1,columns_amount+1)]) + "\n"
    anon_snippet_table = anon_snippet_title+ anon_snippet_body+anon_snippet_end

    # expand anonymous snippet
    snip.expand_anon(anon_snippet_table)
```

Comment: Ah I see you wanted multiple tab stops! Glad you found `snip.expand_anon()`, that's indeed what you want to use here.